# From a forensics standpoint how much leftovers do package managers in Linux leave behind?

Tags: forensics

Let's assume that for my question we're using the equivalent of `apt purge`, which also removes configuration files. What's left behind after `apt purge` and similar commands from other package managers?

I'm guessing it would be loose dependencies and libraries.

Comment: With a physical image of the disk you could probably recover deleted file/folder information as well.

Comment: Autoremove will get the dependencies too.  Everything leaves behind log files.

Comment: So basically only log files?